# Finding the difference between the magnitudes of 2 earthquakes with the intensity of one being 10 times greater than the other's

Tags: calculus

> The Richter scale is a scale that measure the magnitude of an
>   earthquake. In this scale the magnitude $R$ of an earthquake is given
>   by: $$R = log(\frac{I}{I_0})$$
>
> $I_0$ being a fixed intensity.
>
> What is the difference between the magnitudes of 2 earthquakes if the
>   intensity of one is 10 greater than the others?

I did:

$$\frac{I\cdot 10}{I_0}-\frac{I}{I_0} = \frac{I\cdot 10-I}{I_0} = \frac{I\cdot 9}{I_0} = 9$$

But my book says the solution is 1. What did I do wrong?

Comment: $\log x  - \log y \ne x - y$

Comment: If magnitude is a log, why didn't you take any logs in calculating?

Comment: @fleablood I wasn't solving the problem right. I figured it out now (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Call $R_1 = \log\left(\dfrac{I_1}{I_0}\right)$ and $R_2 = \log\left(\dfrac{I_2}{I_0}\right)$. You know that, say, $I_2 = 10 I_1$. Can you see that $R_2-R_1 = 1$, now?

Answer (score 0):

$$log(\frac{I\cdot10}{I_0})-log(\frac{I}{I_0}) = log(\frac{\frac{I\cdot10}{I_0}}{\frac{I}{I_0}}) = log(\frac{I\cdot 10 \cdot I_0}{I_0\cdot I}) = log(\frac{I\cdot 10}{I}) = log(10) = 1$$

Answer (score 0):

That's the difference between *intensities* divided by a fixed intensity.  And if that's what the question asked for that would be the correct answer, as the difference between an intensity that is 10 times another is 9 times a base intensity.

But that is not what the question asked for at all.

The question was about the difference of *magnitudes*.  Magnitude is $\log_{10}\frac I{I_0}$ so you need to figure out what is

$\log_{10}\frac{I*10}{I_0} - \log_{10}\frac{I}{I_0}$.

If you solve that equation, you should see the answer is $1$.